# Do pending system updates hamper server performance?

Tags: windows, automatic-updates

We recently had a production SQL Server max out its CPU to the extent that all we could do was reboot it.  When it came back up, system updates were consuming 48% of CPU.  Updates had been pending for weeks.

My gut instinct has been for a while that when Windows updates are not applied promptly, the machine starts to suffer.

Is there any definitive information on this?

Comment: 48% isn't unusual when updates are being applied.  I don't think the length of time they'd been sitting is likely to be relevant.

Comment: Updates pending install or that have been installed and are pending a reboot are just files on the hard drive. There's no CPU activity related to pending updates or a pending reboot.